# Wordpress Ajax Filter Custom Post Type by Category returns [found_posts":0,]

Tags: php, jquery, filter

I want to output the Post by category through an ajax filter. It works with the standard post type in the same setup but with the custom post type it's showing all post on page load but when I click on a category link it's only showing the right category id "Array ( [action] => filter_wb [category] => 17 )"

And when I output the $query it shows [found_posts":0,],

so I think it's not finding the category content.

I've already checked if the category is empty but when I filter it in the backend the posts are there...
All files are there. jquery works and the xhr is gets the admin-ajax.php 200.

I'm on that for way too long time and can't figure it out.

Maybe you have some tips for me.

//post template

```
</header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="post-filter-wrapper">
            <ul class="post-filter">
                <li><a class="js-filter-item-wb" href="<?= home_url(); ?>">All</a></li>
                <?php 
                $cat_args = array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'category_wb',
                    'exclude' => array(1),
                    'option_all' => 'All'
                );

                $categories = get_categories($cat_args);
                foreach($categories as $cat) : ?>

                <li><a class="js-filter-item-wb" data-category="<?= ($cat->term_id); ?>" href="<?= get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?= $cat->name; ?></a></li>    
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="grid grid--3col-grid js-filter">    
        <?php 

        $args = array (
            'post_type' => 'wuerzburg',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        if($query->have_posts()) : 
            while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
                echo '<div class="grid__post-wrapper" id="post' . get_the_ID() . '">'; // grid-post-wrapper
                echo '<h2 class="grid__preview-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2>';
                echo '<div class="grid__preview-image-wrapper"><a class="grid__preview-image" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</a></div>';
                echo '<div class="grid__the-excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</div>';
                echo '<div class="btn-custom-wrapper"><a class="btn-custom-a btn-custom-a--dark" href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">Vorbeischauen</a></div>';
                echo '</div>'; // end of grid-post-wrapper
            endwhile;
        endif;
        wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
        </div><!-- js-filter -->
```

//jQuery filtering

```
(function($) {
      //$(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on('click', '.js-filter-item-wb', function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();

                  var category = $(this).data('category');

                  $.ajax({
                        url: wp_ajax.ajax_url,
                        data: { action: 'filter_wb', category: category },
                        type: 'post',
                        success: function(result) {
                              $('.js-filter').html(result);
                              console.log('i work')
                        },
                        error: function(result) {
                        console.warn(result);
                        }

                  });
            });



      //});
})(jQuery);
```

//php filter

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_filter_wb', 'filter_wb_ajax' );
add_action('wp_ajax_filter_wb', 'filter_wb_ajax' );


function filter_wb_ajax() {

    $category = $_POST['category'];

    $args = array (
        'post_type' => 'wuerzburg',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,

    );

    if(isset($category)) {
        $args['category__in'] = array($category);
    }

    $query = new WP_Query($args);




    if($query->have_posts()) : 
        while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
            echo '<div class="grid__post-wrapper" id="post' . get_the_ID() . '">'; // grid-post-wrapper
            echo '<h2 class="grid__preview-title"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></h2>';
            echo '<div class="grid__preview-image-wrapper"><a class="grid__preview-image" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '</a></div>';

                //output testing
                echo 'i should print';
                //output testing

            echo '<div class="grid__the-excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt() . '</div>';
            echo '<div class="btn-custom-wrapper"><a class="btn-custom-a btn-custom-a--dark" href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">Vorbeischauen</a></div>';
            echo '</div>'; // end of grid-post-wrapper
        endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata(); 


    print_r($_POST);wp_die();
}
```